# How to include another routes in router file node

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API route in my main `app.js` which have the following code

```
var apiRoutes  = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/api/', apiRoutes);
```

However I need to have separate files for internal API routes
such as

```
api/posts/
api/comments/
api/users/
```

My final result would be to have the following file structure

```
app.js
routes/
      api/
          posts.js
          comments.js
          users.js
```

so each file contain the it's own route After the `/API/` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Otchman try to see  this files

https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation

Comment: Is this the only answer? I was trying to have index.js to reload all the other routes. so I can call it from my app.js

Comment: Please post some example code, or at least a more descriptive answer. Links go dead, and your answer may not be of use to future readers as is.